# Search Recursive Record Type OCaml

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml, record

I am trying to recursively search for a field value in a record that is a recursive record type.

My record type is

```
type node = {node_name:string; node_branch:node list}
```

First, I tried to just traverse a tree like variable of this type:

```
let tree = {node_name="trunk"; node_branch=[{node_name="branch1L:1"; node_branch=[{node_name="branch2L:1"; node_branch=[]};
                                                                                  {node_name="foo_node"; node_branch=[]};];};
                                            {node_name="branch1L:2"; node_branch=[]}];}
    in
    let target = "foo_node" in
    print_newline();
    search_tree_for_name target tree;
```

The idea, is that it is kind of like this:

```
                    trunk
            __________|_________
           |                    |
       branch1L:1           branch1L:2
    ______|_______
   |              |
branch2:1       foo_node
```

So I am searching for a record that has the field value of `node_name = foo_node`. The way I traversed it, just to prove out my logic was:

```
let rec search_tree_for_name target_name in_tree =
  if in_tree.node_name = target_name then
    (* First check the node_name *)
      Format.printf "[%s] Target node_name found\n" in_tree.node_name
  else
    (* Then evaluate the branches *)
    begin
      match in_tree.node_branch with
      | [] ->
         Format.printf "[%s] Branches: 0; End of branch\n" in_tree.node_name
      | head :: tail ->
         Format.printf "[%s] Branches: %i\n" in_tree.node_name (List.length in_tree.node_branch);
         search_tree_for_name target_name head;
         List.iter (search_tree_for_name target_name ) tail;
    end
```

This prints out:

```
[trunk] Branches: 2
[branch1L:1] Branches: 2
[branch2L:1] Branches: 0; End of branch
[foo_node] Target node_name found
[branch1L:2] Branches: 0; End of branch
```

Now, what I really want is to just see if an instance exists where the `node_name` is what I am looking for, so I just want to return a boolean.

What I tried was (I created a new function just for testing purposes):

```
let rec check_tree_for_name target_name in_tree =
  if in_tree.node_name = target_name then
    begin
    (* First check the node_name *)
      Format.printf "[%s] Target node_name found\n" in_tree.node_name;
      true
    end 
  else
    (* Then evaluate the branches *)
    begin
      match in_tree.node_branch with
      | [] ->
         Format.printf "[%s] Branches: 0; End of branch\n" in_tree.node_name;
         false
      | head :: tail ->
         Format.printf "[%s] Branches: %i\n" in_tree.node_name (List.length in_tree.node_branch);
         check_tree_for_name target_name head;
         List.iter (check_tree_for_name target_name ) tail;
    end
```

I am getting the following Error on my function I pass to the `List.iter`:

```
Error: This expression has type node -> bool
       but an expression was expected of type node -> unit
       Type bool is not compatible with type unit
```

Then I changed the last pattern matching block to

```
  | head :: tail ->
     Format.printf "[%s] Branches: %i\n" in_tree.node_name (List.length in_tree.node_branch);
     if check_tree_for_name target_name head then true
     else List.iter (check_tree_for_name target_name ) tail;
```

So that the if conditionals checks the return of the function call and kind of passes it on. Now I have one less error but I still have the same error.

My understanding is that `List.iter` will pass each element of the passed list as the last argument to the function that is passed to `List.iter`. So this should iterate over the elements of my list that I pass to it and the only ways out are if the `node_name` field matches what I am looking for or if it is an empty list.

The major difference I see between my two implementations is that the first one keeps going until all nodes are evaluated and the second implementation goes until  I find what I'm looking for.

Any suggestions would be appreciated and if possible a short explanation of where I am going wrong or at least highlight where I am going wrong (I feel like I'm picking up a lot of functional programming concepts but there still a few that are eluding me).

Comment: Lhooq's answer is right, but I also want to point out that the function you seek is really a one-liner: `let rec check name tree = tree.name = name || List.exists (check name) tree.branches`  (names shortened to fit comment)

Comment: @AndreasRossberg Thank you for that, it's nice to see more idiomatic ways of doing things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in the last branch, if I understand well, you want to know if one of the nodes in `tail` has the good name. In that case, just use `List.exists` :

```
| head :: tail ->
         Format.printf "[%s] Branches: %i\n" in_tree.node_name 
            (List.length in_tree.node_branch);
         check_tree_for_name target_name head ||
         List.exists (check_tree_for_name target_name ) tail
```

And it will work as intended (note the `||` between `check_tree...` and `List.exists ...`. If `check_tree ...` returns `true`, you don't need to check the rest of the list.

---

Small explanation :

In OCaml, all the branches of a pattern matching must have the same type. Here, your first branch had a `boolean` type because you ended it with `false` and the second branch had the `unit` type because you ended it with `List.iter ...`. `List.iter` is of type `('a -> unit) -> 'a list -> unit` and applies its first argument to all the elements in the list given as second argument.
`List.exists` is of type `('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> bool` and returns `true` if one element in the list given as the second argument satisfies the predicate given as the first argument and `false` if no such element exists.

Equivalently, `if cond then e1 else e2` is like a pattern matching so `e1` and `e2` should have the same type so your second attempt was as wrong as the first one. ;-)

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that `List.exists` is a shortcut operator: it will return as soon as a "valid" element has been encountered. If you want to see for yourself: `List.exists (fun x -> print_int x; x = 3) [1;2;3;4;5];;`

Comment: Thanks for this, for me it was obvious but it's worth mentioning it. ;-)

Comment: Yep, that was for the OP and others to read as a sidenote. :)

Comment: Lhooq Thank you for the explanation! That makes sense. I was thinking that the program flow would kind of enter into the function called by List.iter and then exit. I wasn't thinking that it would return. But now I also see in the List documentation that it returns unit. And thanks @RichouHunter for the clarification, that helps!